# добавить в разные div разные значения массива

Tags: php

Вот есть такой рабочий код, но как реализовать заштрихованную часть? Чтобы можно было добраться к разным значениям массива а не только к 1:

```
  <?php
  foreach (array_column($result, 'login') as $loginColumn){//(array_column($result, 'email') as $emailColumn)
    echo "<div class='article'>
      <h2>".$loginColumn."</h2>
      <p>"./*$emailColumn*/"</p>
    </div>";
}?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что вы изобретаете какие-то непонятные методы:

```
foreach ($result as $item) {
    echo "<div class='article'>
      <h2>" . $item['login'] . "</h2>
      <p>" . $item['email'] . "</p>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо)да изобретаю велосипеды) набиваю шишки, знакомлюсь с пэхэпэ